# how to re-map a keyboard key/

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, button-remapping

the shift key in my keyboard has stopped working.(mechanical problem)
so, is there a way so that I can make windows think like (caps-button) is new shift button.
I'll buy a new keyboard ASAP but I need to do some urgent work that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to do this on Windows. Remapping <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> is even one of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Props to Darth Android for the quick and simple (and correct for your situation) solution, but for completeness sake, you can also modify the registry to include a scancode map.

Basically you'll add a `Scan Code` binary key to:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`

Format for it is:

```
00000000 -Header (all zeros)
00000000 -more all zeros
0x000000 -Where x is the number of changes +1
xxxxyyyy -Where x is the scan code, and y is the key your remapping it to.
00000000 -Null entry to show the end
```

So for instance:

```
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,A0,00,5B,00,00,00,00,00
```

Would change your left shift (00A0) to map to your left windows key (005B)

There's a much deeper, in depth article on [Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2155/Keyboard-Remapping-CAPSLOCK-to-Ctrl-and-Beyond.html) if you need to go down that route for a more permanent-ish change, but I wanted to give the other option.  Still... go with Darth Android's solution for your quick fix.  :)

Comment: This actually is what SharpKeys does, IIRC. It's just a fancy GUI over building the scancode map for you and updating the registry! One of the reasons I like it so much. :)

Comment: Nice.  I may start using it myself then instead of my usual "Do I really want to have to look up the scan code and edit the registry or just ignore it?" internal monologue.  :)